# Can threex.geometricglow work with custom geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to THREE.js and i'm looking into ways of adding a glow effect to a mesh to show that it is selected.

I've found a third part library on GitHub;
https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.geometricglow

and a working example here;

http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.geometricglow/examples/geometricglowmesh.html

It seems it should be easy to get this working with the following lines;

```
     var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials[Math.floor(Math.random() * materials.length)]);
     var glowMesh   = new THREEx.GeometricGlowMesh(mesh);
     mesh.add(glowMesh.object3d);
```

But when trying to use it with custom geometry (unlike in the demo) I get the error;

```
Uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

This comes from the dependent script threex.dialategeometry.js

Does anyone know if what i'm trying to do is possible, or if there is a better way to achieve the glow effect i'm looking for?

Full code example (without the library code)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Glow example</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/threex.atmospherematerial.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/threex.dialategeometry.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/threex.geometricglow.js"></script>
<script>
  initialise = function() {
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();
    var height = $(window).innerHeight()-10;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( width, height);

    var cameraDistance = document.cameraDistance = 65;
    var camera = document.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( cameraDistance, width / height, 1, 200);
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.y =0;
    camera.position.z = -60;

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-20,-20,0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-40,0,0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-20,20,0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(20,20,0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(40,0,0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(20,-20,0));

    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,2,3));
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,3,4));
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,4,5));

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide, color: 0xff0000})

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh.doubleSided = true; 

    var glowMesh= new THREEx.GeometricGlowMesh(mesh);
    mesh.add(glowMesh.object3d);

    scene.add(mesh); 

    var tick = function(){
        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }

    $("#container").append(renderer.domElement);
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  }

</script>

</head>

<body onload=initialise()>
   <div id="container"/>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is hard to debug your code without seeing more of it.

Comment: @2pha thanks, please see the full code example i've added. You should be able to get the library code by searching google.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a problem in the THREEx.dilateGeometry class.
I was getting the error trying to apply the glow to a simple sphere, I did manage to get around it by checking for 'undefined' in the THREEx.dilateGeometry class.
You can see it working with my simple alteration in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nojL808c/ . line 25 is the undefined check I added.

```
        if(typeof vertexNormal != 'undefined'){
            vertex.x    += vertexNormal.x * length;
            vertex.y    += vertexNormal.y * length;
            vertex.z    += vertexNormal.z * length;
        }
```

Although this works with a sphere, it will not work with your custom geometry unless you add vertex normals. Here is the same, except with your custom geometry instead of the sphere. http://jsfiddle.net/nojL808c/1/

If I remember correctly, you are doing this to highlight a selected object. If so, I think there are better ways of doing it. Maybe like it is done in the example here: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_buffergeometry.html or like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tcb3z/

Comment: Thanks 2pha, I may be wrong but I think the first alternative example you give may need vertex normals as well, I tried to bring in the code that (I think) highlights the triangles and it didn't work, but I do think it's the way to go, i'll just have to read into it a bit more

Comment: OK, I've tried adding vertex normals by calling  computeVertexNormals() on my geometry object, still nothing. I'm not sure if this should at least in theory be enough though?

Answer (score 0):

Your Vertex Normals probably are not being calculated. Try to use `yourGeometry.computeVertexNormals();`